# issue with loops in vba

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I'm having an issue with this loop. In a spreadsheet, I have a column of values with there being some text that is the same (for example, 5 of the same phrases are said in a row). I've sorted the spreadsheet by the text so I know that if there are multiple instances of the text in the column, they'll all be grouped together. What I'm trying to do is first check if the text has been posted in the second worksheet using the if statement. If its not the same then I post the text in the second worksheet and increase all my variables by one to move on.

For some reason, it's not looping though.

Any help appreciated!

```
Dim ProfCtr As String
Dim S2FreecellH As Integer
Dim ProfCenCellH As Integer

S2FreecellH = 3
ProfCenCellH = 2

ProfCtr = Cells(ProfCenCellH, 4)

Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(S2FreecellH, 1).Value = ProfCtr

While ProfCenCellH < 50
    If Cells(ProfCenCellH, 4).Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(S2FreecellH, 1).Value Then
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(S2FreecellH, 1).Value = ProfCtr
    Else
        ProfCenCellH = ProfCenCellH + 1
    End If

    S2FreecellH = S2FreecellH + 1
    ProfCenCellH = ProfCenCellH + 1
    ProfCtr = Cells(ProfCenCellH, 4)
Wend
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just copy and paste all of the data over, then use excel's remove duplicates function?

Comment: It's part of a larger project (planning to add a lot more loops to this macro) but i have to get this part to work first.

Comment: [Debugging VBA Code](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx)

Comment: @user392500 when I read your post and read your code I face some contradictions (at least in my head), could you post a sample of your worksheet data ? and try to make another workhseet manually with the desired result. It seems to me, that all you realy trying to accomplish is to Macth data in one column in "Sheet1" with another column in "Sheet2". is that true ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the the basics of what you are trying to do are in the code below.  I've put my source column in the same place you had your `ProfCenCellH` (column 4) and my destination column where your `S2FreecellH` was (column 1), but I only loop 15 rather than 50. In the animated gif, notice the source range advances down column 4 and only non-duplicates are transferred to the destination. Remove the `.select` statements from the code once you understand what's going on since they can cause problems.

[image]

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()
Dim destR As Range, sourceR As Range
Set sourceR = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 4)
Set destR = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 1)
destR = sourceR
While sourceR.Row < 15
  sourceR.Select
  Set sourceR = sourceR.Offset(1, 0)
  If sourceR <> destR Then
    Set destR = destR.Offset(1, 0)
    destR = sourceR
  End If
Wend
End Sub
```